# Gson. Deserialize to java object list of new elements with null id

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, primary-key

I have tree of ol and li elements. I am adding this element dynamically. After this I would like to deserialize them into java object. Unfortunatelly I am getting an error:

> `SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/derp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause java.lang.NullPointerException 
>       at com.derp.generic.model.GenericModel.getId(GenericModel.java:28)`

I know this is happening cause my new elements dosnt have an id. But this meant to be that way, cause Id is generated on database server. Normally id I will do such A think (create object assign parameters throught setters, but without id) there will be no error. And after persist this new object will got an id.

The same I am trying to achieve here. After correct deserialisation I would like to make persist this object and that will create an Id for him.

But I have to tell my Gson builder to allow null, or to not try set parameter which isnt declared (is null).

Here is my code:

```
public List<SkeletonElement> toObject(String jsonObject) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .serializeNulls()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Long.class, new LongTypeAdapter())
                .create();
    List<SkeletonElement> list = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, new TypeToken<List<SkeletonElement>>(){}.getType());
    return list;
}
```

Custom adapter which should to the trick:

```
package com.derp.generic.helpers;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

public class LongTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Long>{
@Override
public Long read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    if(reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL){
        reader.nextNull();
        return null;
    }
    String stringValue = reader.nextString();
    try{
        Long value = Long.valueOf(stringValue);
        return value;
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        return null;
    }
}
@Override
public void write(JsonWriter writer, Long value) throws IOException {
    if (value == null) {
        writer.nullValue();
        return;
    }
    writer.value(value);
}
}
```

Generic model where id is declared:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GenericModel<T extends GenericModel<?>> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    public long getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(long id) {this.id = id;}

    public GenericModel() {
    }

    public GenericModel(Long id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And json object with null id object at the end

```
[
    {
        "name": "Title1",
        "id": "1",
        "type": "SkeletonJobElement",
        "parent_id": "null",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Title11",
                "id": "2",
                "type": "SkeletonJobElement",
                "parent_id": "1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Title111",
                        "id": "5",
                        "type": "SkeletonFileElement",
                        "parent_id": "2",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Title112",
                        "id": "6",
                        "type": "SkeletonFileElement",
                        "parent_id": "2",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Title2",
        "id": "3",
        "type": "SkeletonJobElement",
        "parent_id": "null",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Title21",
                "id": "4",
                "type": "SkeletonJobElement",
                "parent_id": "3",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Title3",
        "id": "null",
        "type": "SkeletonJobElement",
        "parent_id": "null",
        "children": []
    }
]
```

Comment: The error is occurring on line 28 of your `GenericModel` class, but the class you provided only has ~19 lines. Did you truncate it? Check the first error at the bottom of the stacktrace. Anyways, looks like the `id` of your `GenericModel` subclass is `null` based on the error. Try changing the type of the `id` getters/setters to `Long`, to match the instance variable they are mutating/accessing.

Comment: Yes. I've truncated unneeded lines. The 28's line is `public long getId() {return id;}` It is null cause the null is in json at first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method returns a primitive `long`. You cannot return a `null` from this method.

```
public long getId() { return id; }
```

Modify the return type to `Long`. The instance variable that this method is returning can be `null`, but the method itself cannot.

```
public Long getId() { return id; }
```

Do the same with the setter.

```
public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }
```

You can also check for `null` before returning.

```
public long getId() { id == null ? 0L : id.longValue(); }
```

Comment: And now it works. Thanks. It was enought to change from primitive long to Long object

Answer (score 0):

If possible change getId to return a Long object rather than a primitive long. The automatic conversion to primitive long causes your null pointer exception.